# Getting a crash every time i press a button"Android Studio"

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, mobile-application

I am trying to make a mobile application,but when ever i try to press the button i get a crash. The button should take me to a new activity page, i have already connect the other pages with the button in a right way. i am just wondering if this code is correct or not:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v)
    {
        Button a1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
    public void onButtonClick1(View c)
    {
        Button a1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
    public void onButtonClick2(View d)
    {
        Button a1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, FourthPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
    public void onButtonClick3(View f)
    {
        Button a1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, FifthPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

i just learned java from some videos in the youtube,so i am not sure if i did the activity function well or not.  Thank you

Comment: Post the logcat please.

Comment: Please, check if the new (called) activity is declared on your Manifest file.

Comment: define finViewById inside  onCreate() method.

Comment: please paste your error lines of logcat

Comment: So, clicking on one button will reset the click listener for another button? That's an odd app setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be few reasons after it

1) Make sure you defined activity in Manifest file

2) check for `android:onClick=""` in xml file..

OR

Try Binding Buttons in `onCreate()` method.

and You can simply use this for onClick

```
a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, i forget to define the activity in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove onClick attribute in your activity_main.xml file and copy and past this code in your **MainActivity.java** file

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b1,b2,b3,b4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
       b2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
       b3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
       b4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, FourthPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, FifthPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **onclick** attribute in layout XML then you doesn't need to set the **onclick** listener. If you are not using **onclick** then you need to set **click listener**. In your case your case, I think use are using **onclick** attribute in layout XML and also trying to set the **click listener** in using java code. so you need to either use **onclick** attribute in layout XML or use **setOnCliickListener()** in java code

Comment: Understood.  Thank you, you have explained it very well to me ^^.